# Red Heifer or Heifer of Soil

Tags: hebrew, numbers, temple, sacrifice

How could we know if

> פרה אדמה

in Num 19:2 refers either to

- a red cow (parah edumah)
- vs a cow of the soil (parah adamah)?

I would like someone to analyse the issue morphologically, grammatically, etymologically relative to Torah as a whole.

Comment: Certainly, I should write "cow of soil" rather than "cow of the soil". However, in English, writing "the soil" would negate the possibility of involvement of cow soil.

Comment: I would appreciate some commentary from anybody downvoting this question - I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

If it meant “cow of soil,” פרת would be written rather than פרה, as פרת is in the construct state, while פרה is in the absolute state.

Comment: You are right. Still researching on the question. Will come back later to clarify. Later means, probably in 2 months'.